# Cannot change Auto-Discover settings in Server Profile in CRM 2015 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to setup Server Side synchronization in a CRM 2015 Online environment. The Email Server Profile is not allowing me to change the Auto-discover settings.

It is set to Yes by default. Is it supposed to be this way?
Or is this a known issue.

Kindly Help.

Comment: That's because it only works with Exchange Online (this is supposed to change in future releases)

Answer (score 0):

*Some what just confirmation of Alex's comment.*

Please see [Supported email service configurations for server-side synchronization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531050.aspx).

> CRM Online supports server-side synchronization with Exchange Online
>   in the same tenant in Office 365 with Server to Server Authentication.
>   Other authentication methods or settings are not recommended or
>   supported, including;
>
> - Setting Auto Discover Server Location to No

So you can do server side synchronisation, but only with Exchange Online which is perhaps why you cant change that setting.

Comment: Thanks James.
I was using Exchange Online itself. I wonder what I missed.